# Drop Down Lists in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, html.dropdownlistfor

In my MVC project (code first approach) I've created a model class for side navigation menu for each user. I need to create a drop down list in the related view that contains the distinct Username(custom field) of the AspNetUsers table. The goal is to show every voice in the NavigationMenus table associated to the related user and create a new one but I don't uderstand how make:
1) the drop down list
2) refresh the page after choosing the desired user in order showing associated records.

Model:

```
public class NavigationMenu
{
    public NavigationMenu()
    {
        MenuChildren = new HashSet<NavigationMenu>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }      
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public int? NavigationMenuId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NavigationMenu> MenuChildren { get; set; }
    public virtual NavigationMenu NavigationMenus2 { get; set; }

    //one-to-many relationships AspNetUsers -> NavigationMenu
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

}
```

Context:

```
public class NavigationMenuContext : DbContext
{

    public NavigationMenuContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")  // connectionstring name define in your web.config
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<NavigationMenu> NavigationMenus { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        // Configure the primary Key for the NavigationMenu 
        modelBuilder.Entity<NavigationMenu>()
            .HasKey(t => t.Id);            

        modelBuilder.Entity<NavigationMenu>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.NavigationMenus2)
            .WithMany(c => c.MenuChildren)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.NavigationMenuId);


        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<siapp.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class NavigationController : Controller
{
    NavigationMenuContext navigationMenuContext;
    public NavigationController()
    {
        navigationMenuContext = new NavigationMenuContext();
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult List()
    {            
        ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(navigationMenuContext.NavigationMenus.Select(m => m.ApplicationUser).Distinct().ToList());                             
        return View();
    }                  

}
```

in the view List.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<siapp.Models.NavigationMenu>

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Role", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("User", (SelectList)ViewBag.Name, " ", new { @class = "form-control" })                
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have this error:

{"The object 'dbo.ApplicationUsers' is not valid."}

***UPDATE:***

I'll try another way:

```
var context = new IdentityDbContext();
var allUsers = context.Users.Select(m => m.UserName).Distinct().ToList();
ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(allUsers);
Return View();
```

there's a way to query ApplicationUser via API to avoid db dependency?

Comment: Just a general observation, you could simplify your life if your application context inherited from IdentityDbContext. Then you can relate to and access ApplicationUser. Also, you might look into [ViewModels](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx) to pass the collections needed for your dropdowns.

Comment: Steve I also tried to inherited from IdentityDbContext by following some tutorials but  is a lot more complicated than solving a puzzle. I always have the same "dbo.ApplicationUsers' is not valid" error. Than I added this property to the model:

    public string UserLogin { get { return ApplicationUser.UserName; } } 

but don't work, I'm at an impasse

Comment: If you are going to reference ApplicationUser, it needs to inherit from IdentityDbContext. Then take out all your DbSets and OnModelCreating code for ApplicationUser since that is handled by the IdentityDbContext behind the scenes.